# Fill field in SSRS with javascript

Tags: javascript, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with a function that detect url of report (the report shows tvo different value, dependending on url)
I use:

```
="javascript: var name=document.URL; var n=name.indexOf('hsbportalen.se'); if(n > 0) { void window.open('http://www.google.com',800,800,'_blank')} else { void window.open('http://www.msn.com',800,800,'_blank')}"
```

But what I want now, is how can I set a value in a textfield (Textbox42) with a JavaScript dependign on url.

Comment: Is the question asking "How can I construct a string in SSRS?". I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll find is that SSRS does not support JavaScript, period. The only functions that you can pass through SSRS are those that your web-browser can interpret outside of a script file. From what I've found, this is a very limited set of commands.

For instance, you can use Window.Open('') and void() and a few others. I've never been able to get an If statement and certainly not a parse() to work through SSRS.

I've had to do this a couple of times and, if you're in the same boat I was, you'll find the easiest way is to do one of the following:

**Option 1: Going from one SSRS Report to Another, Pull data from URL**

Go to the source of the current URL and reconstruct the URL you are receiving. For instance, you can use the "Go to URL" action to create a custom URL to a Report that will [drop the breadcrumbs](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/7/25/using-an-ssrs-url-which-does-not-display-breadcrumbs.html) and use the [Report Server rs & rc parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188712.aspx). Basically, to make this work, whatever variable you want to parse out of the URL would first be created as a parameter of the appropriate type in your target report and then you would pass that value through the URL to that report.

**Scenario 2: Coming from an external website, Pull data from URL**

I've had to do this too, but it's a bit more involved. What you need is an intermediate webpage. One that Opens and Closes immediately, and all it basically does is redirect you to where you want the user to go. To accomplish this, follow these steps:

**First,** create a parameter in the report you want to read the URL. The parameter should be of the appropriate type to store the data to be read from the URL (i.e., URL_Data)

**Second,** create an intermediate webpage that will lie where the URL is pointing. You can construct the page to open with a message like "Loading..." or "Please wait..." (just in case the user sees it).

**Third,** in the script of the intermediate page, have it parse the data from the URL that you are trying to capture. Then, incorporate that data into a custom URL that points to the desired SSRS report and includes the URL data as the parameter.

See [here](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/7/25/using-an-ssrs-url-which-does-not-display-breadcrumbs.html) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188712.aspx) for more information on how to generate custom URLs that can incorporate parameter values.

```
http://SSRS_Server/reportserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/directory/Sample_Report&URL_Data=URL_Snippet
```

**Finally,** finish off your JavaScript on the intermediate webpage to open the SSRS URL in a new window and close the current page.

Now, you can use the values of that parameter wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. It seems to be a litle harder (or more complicated) what I imagined. So I dont Think I going to try it.